# How to use Node modules on the client side?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, module, npm, structure

After installing packages via npm, such as:

```
$ npm install bootstrap
```

or

```
$ npm install angular
```

these are saved inside the "node_modules" by default.
How do you access them (link to them) from an html page?
You can't possibly do "href="/node_modules/", so what's the solution?

I imagine something like:

```
var angular = require("angular");
```

but I'm not sure.

Comment: Use [browserify](http://browserify.org/)!

Comment: Are you already using browserify? That would be an easy way to incorporate them into the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [bower](http://bower.io/), or [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). 
bower - will simplify the process to include js libs
yeoman - will help you to build projects with the the libraries that you need.

Comment: how to include additional node packages in angular. I use yeoman and this seems to be a really basic task, but I failed so far. I tried bower install, npm install, and both including it as a dependency at the module or at the factory (where i need it). I tried the names decladed in the bower.json, as well as in package.json. Must be easy..